How should a manuscript "cut in parts" be evaluated?
This concerns some mathematics papers submitted for review.
Essentially, I have received requests from two different journals asking me to referee papers, which are parts 2 and 3 of a sequence; essentially the titles of the papers are of the form "A mathematical result, part II/III : the case of B/C" respectively. From the way the papers are written, they are clearly spin-offs of the same paper. Presumably, the author(s) thought to split off the original paper into parts to make it easier for each component to be published.
This type of thing is not that uncommon. Perhaps the most famous recent example (to my knowledge) is Bhargava's series of seminal papers titled "Higher Composition Laws I/II/III/IV" (see for example here and here). All of Bhargava's papers in this series are published in the Annals, which is the top journal in (pure) mathematics.
However, it seems to me that most of the time later parts of the series are published in progressively less prestigious journals, because the most important results tend to be announced earlier in the series. The most well-known example of this to me is the series "Primes in tuples" by Goldston, Pintz, and Yildirm, the first in the series was published in the Annals (Primes in tuples I) and the last of which was published in Acta Arithmetica (Primes in tuples IV). This to me seems to be the more common situation.
What criteria would you apply to justify publishing all parts of a series of papers in equally prestigious journals, and in what situations is it more justified for later parts of the series to be published in less prestigious journals?
In particular, should subsequent parts of the series be judged in line with the first part? That is, should they be considered part of the "same" paper and therefore equally strong/weak? Or should each individual part be judged on their own? The latter seems hard, due to the natural inter-connectedness of the series.

Are you sure that the "less prestigious" journal was the first choice of the author or a compromise after rejection elsewhere? Publishing is up to the publisher, not the author(s).

@Buffy I added a paragraph clarifying my question.

So you got two papers sent by two different journals. Did any of the editors indicate to you that you should take into account the fact that there are more papers in the series? My gut feeling is that each of the papers should be reviewed on its own merits, as independently as possible from the others, unless you were explicitly asked otherwise.

"What criteria would you apply to justify publishing all parts of a series of papers in equally prestigious journals, and in what situations is it more justified for later parts of the series to be published in less prestigious journals?" I'm not sure why you ask this, because as reviewer your job is to assess each paper exactly for the journal to which it has been submitted.

"That is, should they be considered part of the "same" paper and therefore equally strong/weak?" If the editors didn't send you the parts of the paper other than the one they asked you to review, they rather obviously don't expect you to take the other parts into account.

@ChristianHennig I can certainly appreciate the perspective you offer, thank you
